# JSON file reading from Hadoop HDFS using C#.NET

Tags: json, hadoop

I am trying to read json file from HDFS to file stream and i am getting exception.

private string ReadHadoopJasonFiles(){//set variables     string destFolderName = "/demo/ufo/in";
            string destFileName = "admingroups_metadata.json";

```
        //connect to hadoop cluster
        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://localhost:50070");
        string userName = "hadoop";
        string srcFilename = destFolderName + "/" + destFileName;
        //string srcFilename = @"C:\FilesForHadoopJason\admingroups_metadata.xml";
        WebHDFSClient myClient = new WebHDFSClient(Convert.ToString(myUri), userName);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(srcFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string json;
        try
        {
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string repalcedjson = json.Replace("\"", "'");
            return repalcedjson;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            sr.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024893
  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\user\projects\PoC_\challengeOpenDump20140701160001_admingroups.json'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
       at ConsoleApplication1.HadoopJsonToRdbms.ReadHadoopJasonFiles() in c:\Users\DXG8488\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 111
       at ConsoleApplication1.HadoopJsonToRdbms.JsonToRDBMSControler() in c:\Users\DXG8488\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 29
       at ConsoleApplication1.HadoopJsonToRdbms.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\DXG8488\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 24
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

Comment: File not found exception is coming .Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exception, where it comes from and the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Sharphadoop](https://sharphadoop.codeplex.com/) 
here is an example of a reading a Json Hadoop REST API

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url_path) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; // Get method            
req.Accept = "application/json"; // accept json
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
return result;
```

Comment: What is your problem. Learn how to ask question http://stackoverflow/help/how-to-ask